# Django model limit choices based on another model but with a specific field value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have got 2 models, simplified for this question. In the `Article` model, how can I limit the `choices=` of the field `Article.status` based on the entries in the `Category` model which have a specific `Category.type` value?

```
class Article(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  # Set choices= only to values of Category which have a type of 'foo'
  status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=)

class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

For transparency, I know I've done this before but I can't seem to remember how or find the project where I did it. It's like the solution just disappeared on me...**poof**. Magic.

Comment: and what is the relation exactly between `Category.type` and `Article.status` ?

Comment: you could set `status = models.ForeignKey(Category)` which will limit the choices based on entry in `Category`

Comment: It looks like a substantive edit was made on this question after an answer came in, to the degree that it invalidates the answer. We want to preserve questions and answers such that answers can be seen to naturally flow from questions above them, so that future readers can understand what is on the page. I have thus rolled back to the earlier version. (If you separately wish to record an answer, a self-answer is most welcome).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like limit_choices_to in your models.py :

```
category = model.ForeignKey(Category,limit_choices_to={'type':'the type you want'}
```

If you want something more dynamic, or more detailed, you can specify your custom queryset of a specific field in the **init** of a ModelForm like :

```
self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(type='type_you_wanted')
```

If you want to display the category dynamically depending of which category.type are selected in the form then you should see this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How could I forget `limit_choices_to` and an even bigger blunder type in `CharField` and not `ForeignKey`. Thanks my man.

Comment: Learned something new, Thanks